# FireBird IBExpert ошибка подключения

Tags: sql, база-данных, windows, tcp, firebird

пытаюсь создать базу данных в IBExpert, указываю локальный сервер, путь к fdb файлу, логин и пароль соответственно по классике SYSDBA masterkey, charset UTF-8

И ошибка:

```
 Unsuccessful execution caused a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements. 
 Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version.
```

Библиотеку явно указал fbclient.dll (забросил её в syswow64), до этого была gds32.dll, ошибки те же самые..Firebird установил с оф. сайта версию 3.0.7 32-bit (битность как у IBExpert)

В гугле не смог найти решение в итоге..Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём трабл((

**P.S.** Специально открыл в брандмауэре порт 3050 (проверил telnet'ом, работает) и занёс в работу с ним firebird и ibexpert
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: FDB у вас от этой версии сервера? Между версиями они не совместимы.

Comment: Ну и как проверить? Даже если я сам вручную создам файлик fdb, все равно будет проблема

Comment: Ну как - перебирать версии сервера, пока не заработает. Чтобы перенести базу с места на место, нужно сделать бекап на старом сервере, а потом восстановление на новом

Comment: @gbg, много всего Вы написали...Я не особо шарю в этом, мне лишь бы сделать так, чтоб просто таблица заработала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и написано в ошибке, следует прочитать соответствующий параграф Release Notes. Там написано, что надо подключиться в Embedded режиме к любой базе и создать любого пользователя с плагином Srp.

Answer (score 0):

Опишу свой случай, схожий на ваш, может вам поможет или тому кто зайдет через поиск.
По рабочей необходимости перешел с **windows 7** на **windows 10**, и вот решил возобновить проектную деятельность под **Firebird+IBExpert+Delphi**.
Установил **Firebird** (Firebird-4.0.2.2816-0-x64.exe), затем **IBExpert** (2022.3.4.1) и финалочкой **Delphi 11.2** (lite 17.2). Пути установки по-умолчанию. Ничего не предвещало беды. Через эксперта попробовал создать новую БД - ошибка! По тексту догадался, что защита файлов субд от записи.
Установил **Firebird** в другой каталог. Пробую снова - ошибка, только уже другая. Пробую через **isql** создать базу - создается, прописываю ее в алиас (**databases.conf**) и подключаюсь снова через **isql** - норм. Странно, но едем дальше. Зарегистрировал в эксперте созданную базу, пробую подключиться к ней по темже реквизитам и ловлю следующие сигналы:

```
Attempting to connect to:

Unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource.
unavailable database.
SQLCODE: -904
GDSCODE: 335544375

Unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource.
Cannot attach to services manager.
SQLCODE: -904
GDSCODE: 335544792
```

Матюки и запросы к гуглу не дали ожидаемых результатов. 
Отчаившись чтото вразумительное найти, я решил поискать либу **gds32.dll** и понять, может она затерялась или еще чего. И нашел их аж 4 шт.!

```
c:\Windows\System32\GDS32.DLL
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\gds32.dll
c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Interbase\redist\InterBase2020\win32\gds32.dll
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\InterBase2020\bin\
```

Вот те на, какой еще **InterBase2020**, который я даже не устанавливал. И потом дошло, что он установился вместе с **Delphi 11.2**.
Я переустановил делфи (снес все доп. пакеты), удалил все **gds32.dll**, и заново переустановил **Firebird**. Все, теперь все работает отлично в эксперте: и создает, и регистрирует и подключается.
**Вывод:** небрежная установка новой незнакомой версии делфи (полная установка) сломала отлаженную годами схему :) и подарила мне 2 вечера отличного времяпровождения, вместо плодотворного труда.